# Selenium C# Stale Element error after Page Refresh

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with the bot giving an error for "stale element" but it's only after the first "officer". At first I thought it had to do with there not being enough time to refresh the page so the elements technically didn't exist but then after I added a thread.sleep it still was throwing the error.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace bot_test
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //  url used to create this -https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html 

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\");

            // To change the date to find and replace datetovar to the date 
            //To change the date from find and replace darefromvar to the date
            // Don't forget to switch the date back to the var format

            string datefromvar = "12/05/2019";
            string datetovar = "12/21/2019";


            driver.Url = "https://odyssey.gwinnettcourts.com/Portal/Home/Dashboard/26";
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            //  Officer 1- Argo, James .R

            // Category Select
            IWebElement typeElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cboHSSearchBy"));
            var typeSelect = new SelectElement(typeElement);
            typeSelect.SelectByValue("JudicialOfficer");



            // JudicialOfficer ID
            IWebElement officerId = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selHSJudicialOfficer"));
            var officerIdSelect = new SelectElement(officerId);
            officerIdSelect.SelectByValue("12942");

            // Date From
            IWebElement fromDate = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SearchCriteria_DateFrom"));
            fromDate.SendKeys(datefromvar);

            // Date To
            IWebElement toDate = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SearchCriteria_DateTo"));
            toDate.SendKeys(datetovar);

            // Click Button
            IWebElement buttonSubmitElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnHSSubmit"));

            buttonSubmitElement.Click();

            driver.Navigate().Back();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

            //  Officer 2- Assistance, Judicial

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            IWebElement typeElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cboHSSearchBy"));
            typeSelect.SelectByValue("JudicialOfficer");

            IWebElement officerId2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selHSJudicialOfficer"));
            officerIdSelect.SelectByValue("19024"); //Assistance, Judicial

            fromDate.SendKeys(datefromvar);

            toDate.SendKeys(datetovar);

            buttonSubmitElement.Click();

            driver.Navigate().Back();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);

            //  Officer 3- Ballar Christopher, A

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            IWebElement typeElement3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cboHSSearchBy"));
            typeSelect.SelectByValue("JudicialOfficer");

            IWebElement officerId3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selHSJudicialOfficer"));
            officerIdSelect.SelectByValue("12933"); //Ballar Christopher, A

            fromDate.SendKeys(datefromvar);

            toDate.SendKeys(datetovar);


            buttonSubmitElement.Click();

            driver.Navigate().Back();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a StaleElementException is and what causes it? If not, you should spend some time researching it. Once you understand that, fixing it will be much easier.

Comment: I have looked more into it and added an answer. For some reason I thought it would be a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this a lot more and realized the issue was the fact that I didn't declare new web elements for the "typeElement", "officerIdSelect", "toDate", "fromDate" and "buttonSubmitElement"  on each new page refresh causing the elements that I was trying to use to become stale.

The new code that fixed the error is below.

It may not be the most efficient as I'm not a C# or Selenium Master but it works.

```
//  Officer 3- Ballar Christopher, A

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            IWebElement typeElement3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(elemSrchByStr));
            var typeSelect3 = new SelectElement(typeElement3);
            typeSelect3.SelectByValue(judOfficer);

            IWebElement officerId3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(officerSrchByStr));
            var officerIdSelect3 = new SelectElement(officerId3);
            officerIdSelect3.SelectByValue("12933"); //Ballar Christopher, A

            IWebElement fromDate3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(srchDateFrom));
            fromDate3.SendKeys(dateFromVar);

            IWebElement toDate3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(srchDateTo));
            toDate3.SendKeys(dateToVar);

            IWebElement buttonSubmitElement3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(button));
            buttonSubmitElement3.Click();

            driver.Navigate().Back();
```